# AngularJS ui-select multiple, forbid backspace key to delete item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backspace

I have an AngularJS multiple ui-select control. I need to prevent the backspace key to delete selected items (tags). This is a jsfiddle found on SO while searching about this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/v1df0erv/

It mostly describes what I have. But once tags are added, I need to not allow the backspace key to delete them.

Thanks.

Comment: Should they be removed by clicking the "x"?

Comment: you should use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup

Comment: Yes, they should be removed by "x". Just not by backspace. I tried keyup, also down and press, and preventDefault, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use ui-lock-choice="true" on ui-select-match element. like explained here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select-match